# Pandas Timeseries Data - Calculating product over intervals of varying length

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have some timeseries data that basically contains information on price change period by period. For example, let's say:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['TimeStamp','PercPriceChange'])
df.loc[:,'TimeStamp']=[1457280,1457281,1457282,1457283,1457284,1457285,1457286]
df.loc[:,'PercPriceChange']=[0.1,0.2,-0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,-0.1]
```

so that df looks like

```
     TimeStamp  PercPriceChange
0    1457280              0.1
1    1457281              0.2
2    1457282             -0.1
3    1457283              0.1
4    1457284              0.2
5    1457285              0.1
6    1457286             -0.1
```

What I want to achieve is to calculate the overall price change before the an increase/decrease streak ends, and store the value in the row where the streak started. That is, what I want is a column 'TotalPriceChange' :

```
   TimeStamp   PercPriceChange               TotalPriceChange   
0    1457280              0.1             1.1 * 1.2  - 1 = 0.31
1    1457281              0.2                         0
2    1457282             -0.1                        -0.1
3    1457283              0.1           1.1 * 1.2 * 1.1  - 1 = 0.452
4    1457284              0.2                         0
5    1457285              0.1                         0
6    1457286             -0.1                        -0.1
```

I can identify the starting points using something like:

```
df['turn'] = 0
df['PriceChange_L1'] = df['PercPriceChange'].shift(periods=1, freq=None, axis=0)
df.loc[ df['PercPriceChange'] * df['PriceChange_L1'] < 0, 'turn' ] = 1
```

to get

```
    TimeStamp   PercPriceChange             turn
0    1457280              0.1          NaN or 1?
1    1457281              0.2             0
2    1457282             -0.1             1
3    1457283              0.1             1
4    1457284              0.2             0
5    1457285              0.1             0
6    1457286             -0.1             1
```

Given this column "turn", I need help proceeding with my quest (or perhaps we don't need this "turn" at all). I am pretty sure I can write a nested for-loop going through the entire DataFrame row by row, calculating what I need and populating the column 'TotalPriceChange', but given that I plan on doing this on a fairly large data set (think minute or hour data for couple of years), I imagine nested for-loops will be really slow.

Therefore, I just wanted to check with you experts to see if there is any efficient solution to my problem that I am not aware of. Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: I help you with that  `df.loc[ df['PercPriceChange'] * df['PriceChange_L1'] < 0, 'turn' ] = 1` and then `df.turn = df.turn.fillna(0)`

Comment: @unutbu Yep, I was just trying to illustrate my thought (so I said "something like"). I've edited the codes based on Lucas 's comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The calculation you are looking for looks like a groupby/product operation. 
To set up the groupby operation, we need to assign a `group` value to each row. Taking the cumulative sum of the `turn` column gives the desired result:

```
df['group'] = df['turn'].cumsum()
# 0    0
# 1    0
# 2    1
# 3    2
# 4    2
# 5    2
# 6    3
# Name: group, dtype: int64
```

Now we can define the `TotalPriceChange` column (modulo a little cleanup work) as

```
df['PercPriceChange_plus_one'] = df['PercPriceChange']+1
df['TotalPriceChange'] = df.groupby('group')['PercPriceChange_plus_one'].transform('prod') - 1
```

---

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'PercPriceChange': [0.1, 0.2, -0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1, -0.1],
                   'TimeStamp': [1457280, 1457281, 1457282, 1457283, 1457284, 1457285, 1457286]})

df['turn'] = 0
df['PriceChange_L1'] = df['PercPriceChange'].shift(periods=1, freq=None, axis=0)
df.loc[ df['PercPriceChange'] * df['PriceChange_L1'] < 0, 'turn' ] = 1 

df['group'] = df['turn'].cumsum()

df['PercPriceChange_plus_one'] = df['PercPriceChange']+1
df['TotalPriceChange'] = df.groupby('group')['PercPriceChange_plus_one'].transform('prod') - 1
mask = (df['group'].diff() != 0)
df.loc[~mask, 'TotalPriceChange'] = 0

df = df[['TimeStamp', 'PercPriceChange', 'TotalPriceChange']]
print(df)
```

yields

```
   TimeStamp  PercPriceChange  TotalPriceChange
0    1457280              0.1             0.320
1    1457281              0.2             0.000
2    1457282             -0.1            -0.100
3    1457283              0.1             0.452
4    1457284              0.2             0.000
5    1457285              0.1             0.000
6    1457286             -0.1            -0.100
```

Comment: Perfect! I thought about groupby & product, but was not able to figure out how to generate the group tags - your .cumsum() did the magic. Thanks so much!